# "npx react-native start" hangs

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

#### Introduction

I'm attempting to create a Hello World style program with React Native 0.63.3 using the [official docs](http://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). I'm using to the *React Native CLI Quickstart* path in that link.

#### What I've Done So Far

I've gotten to the section:
**Running your React Native application**
**Step 1: Start Metro**

And I've run:

```
npx react-native start --verbose
```

And I get the following output:

```
               ######                ######               
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
             ##  ########################  ##             
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
 ##             ###     ##########     ###             ## 
  ##           ####      ########      ####           ##  
   ###         ## ###      ####      ### ##         ###   
      ###     ##    ##              ##    ##     ###      
          ######    ###            ###    ######          
             ##  ########################  ##             
            ##         ###      ###         ##            
            ##           ##    ##           ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##             ####             ##            
            ##          ###    ###          ##            
             ###     ####        ####     ###             
               ######                ######               
                                                          
debug Checking for a newer version of React Native
debug Current version: 0.63.3
debug Cached release version: 0.60.0
debug Checking for newer releases on GitHub
                 Welcome to React Native!
                Learn once, write anywhere



To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

debug Latest release: 0.60.0
```

Pressing "r" gives the following:

```
No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app...
```

Pressing "d" gives the following:

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Opening developer menu...
```

#### Question

*How do I successfully run and finish the Metro process so that I can run my React Native application?*

Comment: you also need to start with an emulator (npx react-native ios) or (npx react-native android)

Comment: Oh nice! Got this working using `npx react-native run-android`. I'll let you answer this question if you want the rep, otherwise I'll self-answer soon.

Comment: This documentation isn't stellar. I always wait for a step to finish before moving on to the next and I didn't know that Metro runs continuously in the background. There isn't any output of the command that screams out to me that everything is working as intended.

Comment: thanks! - answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `npx react-native start`, you're running the build, however, to run the application, you'll need to choose to run either on `android` or on `ios`. [source:](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

android:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

ios: ([mac](https://reactnative.dev/docs/_getting-started-macos-ios#step-2-start-your-application))

```
npx react-native run-ios
```